# Converting Array of Lists to Keras Input

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

Given an array of the form

```py
array([list([21603, 125, 737, 579, 2065, 10399, 1175, 0, 0, 0]),
       ...
       list([1896, 3917, 498, 296, 1452, 523, 754, 450, 3795, 341])],
      dtype=object)
```

How do you prepare it to be consumed by a Keras model in TensorFlow 2.0 RC0? In its current form it throws the error

> ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).

and I can't seem to get it in the form I'm familiar with,

```py
array([[21603, 125, 737, 579, 2065, 10399, 1175, 0, 0, 0],
       ...
       [1896, 3917, 498, 296, 1452, 523, 754, 450, 3795, 341]])
```

Comment: Show us how you're generating the array

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo wouldn't that be a separate question, though? ("How do I not get here in the first place?")

Comment: Yes, but from looking at your example it seems like some rows might have different lengths, and you either have to create a tensor from the start, or pad it with zeros

Comment: All of the rows in my data have the same number of elements (I tried to make that clear in my example, but the numbers being different lengths makes it not obvious), in the example each has 10 items (the first row has 7 items, padded with 3 0s).

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo I take that back, you may be right. It looks like the code I'm using to pad doesn't truncate lists longer than the max length. Testing it now, it'll take ~15 minutes to encode. If this can be formulated as an appropriate, valid answer ("this is sometimes indicative of array elements being different lengths") I'll gladly accept.

Comment: Didn't help. I guess I need to post a question with my workflow to see how not to arrive here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you find yourself in this situation, you can correct your array(s) with the following:

```py
new_array = np.array(list(x for x in old_array))
```